# How to feed Watson Assistant context variable before arriving at Assistant node V2 on node red

Tags: variables, bots, telegram, node-red, watson-assistant

Right
I integrated Watson Assistant with Telegram using Node Red.

It is working as expected. When sending a message it responds instantly.

So I will be a "$username" variable in the Watson responses and I am not able to assign a value to it (img1).

[image: Img1]

as the Watson node receives a paload with the content of the message sent by the telegram (img2), I don't know how to pass the user along.

[image: Img2]

And finally Watson returns the answer with one more space as it is expected to receive the variable before going through the Assistant node (img3).

[image: Img]

the full flow is here. Now I just need to somehow assign the telegram's first_name to this $user variable

[image: flow]

thanks in advance

Comment: image 1 and 2 were swapped by mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You add additional context data by adding to `msg.additional_context`. eg.

```js
msg.additional_context.user = 'XYZ'
```

or

```js
msg.additional_context['user'] = 'XYZ'
```

Comment: OOOH
it really worked
Thank you very much!